# Windows Web Server 2008 vs Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows

Recently came across [Microsoft Windows Web Server 2008](http://www.iis.net/default.aspx?tabid=27). I believe its a lighter version of Windows Server 2008.

I couldn't understand the difference between two and which one should be good for our business?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find all differences between the different editions on this page:

[Windows Server 2008: Overview of Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-editions-overview.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are only running basic websites, then it might be the answer for you. There are various restrictions on what you can and can't install. if you could describe your business, then someone might be able to give a more helpful answer. You will probably find you can do very little with it apart from hosting websites. Try these links:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/compare-features.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/compare-roles.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/differentiated-features.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/compare-core-installation.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/compare-specs.aspx